# RadioButton symbol not resolved in Android Studio

Tags: android

I'm getting a "cannot resolve symbol variable" on `maleButton`, on the bottom where the femaleSelected is. I've defined the `RadioButton`s in `onCreate()`. I thought `onCreate()` was `protected`, and that's why I couldn't access the buttons. But changing it into `public` solves nothing.

Here's the relevant code:

```
package ideaman924.playground;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RadioButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RadioButton maleButton,femaleButton;
        maleButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.male);
        femaleButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.female);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void femaleSelected(View view) {
        maleButton.toggle(); // error
    }

}
```

Any idea why this is happening?

EDIT: Here is also the XML layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="Select gender" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/female"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="female"
        android:onClick="femaleSelected" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/male"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="male"
        android:onClick="maleSelected" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please can you add your xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `RadioButton malebutton` is a **local variable** and it is visible only in that method.

If you want to see it at the class level, you should move

```
    RadioButton malebutton,femalebutton;
```

after

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

Read about [variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html).

Answer (score 0):

you need to define RadioButton malebutton out of onCreate method global variable for your class.

```
    RadioButton malebutton,femalebutton;     
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //RadioButton maleButton,femaleButton;
    maleButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.male);
    femaleButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.female);
    }
```